# Put a label near the edge of a Grid object

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, labeling

I have a `Grid` object and want to put a label near its corner or edge. The label will **overlap** with the boundary, not fully inside the `Grid` region. The following example doesn't work well since the label is partly concealed. Note that I need to work with `Grid` rather than `GraphicsGrid`.

```
plot = Grid[
   Table[Plot[Sin[i x + j \[Pi]/3], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]];
Labeled[plot, "Label", {{Bottom, Right}}, Spacings -> {Automatic, -0.5}]
Labeled[plot, "Label", {{Bottom, Center}}, Spacings -> {Automatic, -0.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Legended` and `Placed` instead of `Labeled`:

```
plot = Grid[
   Table[Plot[Sin[i x + j \[Pi]/3], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]];
Legended[plot, {Placed["Label", {1, 0.05}]}]
```

[image: Legended]

Comment: I actually had tried this, but it can't put the label across the boundary. Not what I need. Sorry if the original title misled you.

Comment: What about this inelegant workaround with ``Spacings``: ``plot = Grid[Table[Plot[Sin[i x + j \[Pi]/3], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {i, 2}, {j, 2}], Spacings -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5}}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Transparent]; Legended[plot, {Placed["Label", {1, 0}]}]``

Comment: Thanks. It somewhat works. I'm surprised that turning on `Frame` can have such an effect. Let's see if any other answers.